# Is there any geometrical/homological intuition behind symmetrized gradient?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-operators, geometric-measure-theory

The gradient/differential/exterior differential/divergence/curl are all strictly related first order differential operators. As far as I understood, they are the base of (co)homological theories in Euclidean spaces/Riemannian manifolds. As an instance of what I am saying just consider the spaces of $k$-differential forms in $\mathbb R^3$ and the various $d$ operators acting between them (which turn out to be - I guess the magic word is "Hodge dual to" - the usual divergence/curl we learn in Calculus).

I am wondering if symmetrized gradient ($\frac{1}{2}(\nabla + \nabla^T)$) can be given a similar interpretation.

The flavour of the question is of course geometric, the applications I have in mind are rather analytical: the original question stems from the well-known fact that [$BV$ functions are $n$-dimensional normal currents in $\mathbb R^n$,](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Function_of_bounded_variation#Link_to_the_theory_of_currents) while I do not know if such an identification is possible for functions of bounded *deformation*, i.e. functions whose symmetric gradient is a measure.

Comment: I know something about that and I will write what I know when I have time. If you do not see my answer within 24 hours, please leave a comment for me with a reminder since I may forget about your question.

Comment: Note that the gradient operator corresponds to the $d$ operator under the musical isomorphism, so for cohomological purposes it suffices to consider symmetrized $d$.  If I'm not confusing myself, $d$ has the same kernel and cokernel as symmetrized $d$, both viewed as graded operators on the graded exterior algebra of the tangent bundle, so they are cohomologically equivalent (though doing computations with explicit representatives of cohomology classes may feel a bit different).

Comment: I'll also add that $d$ and symmetrized $d$ induce the same class in the K-homology of the underlying manifold, so one can pass freely back and forth between them for the purposes of index theory and such.

Comment: This operator shows up in linear elasticity, see e.g. http://calvino.polito.it/~salamon/seminar/srni99.pdf https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2010-47-02/S0273-0979-10-01278-4/ and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00205-014-0806-1 for some work on the "elasticity complex".

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I am sorry to bother you but, if you have some time, I would read with pleasure your comment/answer (especially concerning the link between BD functions and currents). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Romeo I realized I do not have much to say and probably you know all what I know. I just wanted to list some work on spaces of bounded deformation, but I guess you know the literature.